# as.factor conversion error

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to convert three character variables in a data frame to factors, and I keep getting an error for one of the three. The problematic variable, fund.category, has 4 possible values: "Undefined", "Small", "Large Existing", and "Large New Construction". My code follows - I first read the data frame from an excel sheet using XLConnect, then dropped unnecessary variables and renamed the ones that I kept:

```
a.projects <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet = "ProjectsDetail")
a.projects.2 <- a.projects[c("ProjectNumber", "BusinessType", "Fund.Category")]
a.projects.2 <- rename(a.projects.2,
                       c("ProjectNumber" = "project.number",
                         "BusinessType" = "business.type",
                         "Fund.Category" = "fund.catetgory"))
str(a.projects.2)
a.projects.2$project.number <- as.factor(a.projects.2$project.number)
a.projects.2$business.type <- as.factor(a.projects.2$business.type)   
a.projects.2$fund.category <- as.factor(a.projects.2$fund.category)
```

Here is the structure of a.projects.2, produced before I tried to do the factor conversions:

```
'data.frame':   4291 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ project.number: chr  "APS-10-02825" "APS-10-02826" "APS-10-02876" "APS-10-03134" ...
 $ business.type : chr  "Office" "Office" "Process Industrial" "K-12 School" ...
 $ fund.catetgory: chr  "Undefined" "Undefined" "Large Existing" "Large New Construction" ...
```

And here is the error from the console:

```
a.projects.2$fund.category <- as.factor(a.projects.2$fund.category)

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "fund.category", value = integer(0)) : 
replacement has 0 rows, data has 4291
```

The same code produced no errors for my other two character variables (project.number and business.type). Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the actual data using `dput(head(a.projects.2))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have misspelled "fund.category" in your earlier statement:

```
a.projects.2 <- rename(a.projects.2,
                       c("ProjectNumber" = "project.number",
                         "BusinessType" = "business.type",
                         "Fund.Category" = "fund.catetgory"))
```

Fix the typo and it should be happy :-)

---

To understand the error,

`a.projects.2$fund.category` returns `NULL`

`as.factor(NULL)` returns `factor(0)`

and it is when assigning `factor(0)` to `a.projects.2$fund.category` that you get the error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "fund.category", value = integer(0)) : 
replacement has 0 rows, data has 4291
```

Comment: Ha! I knew it must have been something stupid... thanks! And I appreciate the error message explanation, that'll help for future problems.